# Passing R functions to C as C functions

Tags: c++, c, r, compilation, abstract-syntax-tree

## Background

I am writing a package implementing a specific optimization algorithm in R for various pre-specified objective functions (functions to optimize). The optimization code itself is written in C. In order to make the code as efficient as possible I also re-implemented the objective function in C. At the current stage the role of R is to provide an interface to the C code using .Call.

## Goal

I would like the package to be able to handle any user supplied objective function. However, I do not want to call R functions from C, that would incur a large overhead and will most likely be excruciatingly slow.

**What I really want is a way to pass a limited class of R functions (Those you would typically see as cost functions in statistical and machine learning) as a parameter, have this R function converted to a C function** and then subsequently used as an objective function in the optimization algorithm.

## Solution Idea

R has a strong parenting with LISP. It is pretty straight forward to get a function's abstract syntax tree(AST). I am thinking it *may* be possible to parse the AST as a C function and then either compile it or just pass it dynamically (I don't know if that is even is doable in C)

## Questions

- Is the solution idea above even feasible?
- Is there any other way to do this?
- What must I learn to be able to do this?

Note: Doing this as an R package is not necessary. Trying to do this inside the rigid structure of an R package might make things even more difficult.

Comment: See this example on how to call R from C: https://gist.github.com/Sharpie/323498

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am aware. But this is not what I want. I do not want to call R functions from C. I want to **turn** R functions into C functions.

Comment: I don't think that there is a large overhead in calling R from C. Every time you execute a line in R you are calling some C function. However, I don't think that what you ask is feasible and efficient in general. If it were, every R function would be translated in C and then in R you just had simple wrapper to call the C function.

Comment: There is an inherently large overhead due to the fact that the R objective functions is going to be slow and called several thousands of times during the optimization. As for the efficiency, this kind of approach was very successfully implemented several python packages (for instance in Theano.)

Comment: I admit that I'm not much expert in this territory, but I would be very surprised if you could enhance the efficiency of an R function through a translator that could possibly translate any function. Why it hasn't been done?

Comment: Well It does work quite well in python. Again you should check Theano and Cython. I have no idea why it hasn't been implemented in R.

Comment: Because you can't do this. With a language this established and popular, do you _really_ think you are the first person to think about this?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel . Of course not. That's why my first question is if it's even possible. I would really appreciate some directions to understand why it is possible in python and not in R.

Comment: Its not possible in python. Theano and cython are *nothing* like a way to turn arbitrary python functions into C. They have strictly limited ranges of functionality. A similar system in R is possible, but it would be in the realm of some "little language" of simple array processing, rather than full R.

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks. You made me realise that the way I formulated my question makes it too broad. I was actually only thinking of functions you would typically see as cost functions in statistical and machine learning problems.

Comment: Okay, write a formal spec for such a thing and then you should be able to figure out if its possible to transcode it into C or C++ and then dynamically load it with Rcpp. Its probably easier to learn C or C++.

Answer (score 8):

Some pointers at prior experiments:

- [R to C compiler at Rice](http://www.hipersoft.rice.edu/rcc/): abandonded
- [R to C compiler by Simon](http://www.rforge.net/r2c/): also stale.
- R and LLVM attempts by Duncan Temple Lang:  There are two packages, and a published paper, yet (seemingly) nobody uses it.  Been a while since I read the paper(s) but one limitation was that it didn't even attempted to cover all of R.

One of the reasons you can't easily do this is that the languages excels at computing on the language as well as non-standard evaluation versus standard evaluation, promises, forced evaluation and so.

Lastly, for your narrow case of passing a *compiled objective function* to an optmizer: see my [RcppDE package](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=RcppDE) which does that.

H/t to Josh for the reminder about Simon's attempt.

Comment: [Renjin](http://www.renjin.org/) compiles a reasonably large swath of R code to Java for reasonable performance (I'm told). Relevant for understanding the challenges of compiling R, though obviously not to C and the original question. Somehow it seems like 'native' C / C++ code should be easy to handle via JNI, but I guess that's arm-chair programming.

Comment: It cannot deal with Rcpp so by its reverse depends being somewhat far-reaching, it excludes a large set of CRAN.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations and references. However, What I am asking is much more limited in scope. How, if it is possible, to go about writing a mathematical expression compiler that would turn R mathematical expressions into C. If this can be done, the next step for me would be to study RcppDE code to see how to encapsulate and pass an external pointer object encapsulating the pointer to the compiled C function to the C optimizer.